# Open an Android app from a directory on sdcard

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-external-storage, kiosk-mode

I have a client that uses android devices with a kiosk mode. They have a kiosk mode manager that only allows apps they add to it to be opened. I was informed the kiosk manager opens apps from the Android/data directory on the device (from one of the com.google.x type directories). I've been attempting to have on of those directories created by this app so they can launch it from their kiosk manager, but haven't had much luck. I can see the directory I'm looking for in the Device File Manager under data/data/com.x and data/app/com.x, but is there a way for me to get those files to be located under sdcard instead of data? The app also doesn't give me an option to manually move it to external storage, so I'm not sure if that's part of the problem. The devices are running Android 8.1.0 and the app just sends user input data to a server on the network.

Essentially, they want to be able to view the app files from the device and also open the app from a directory on the sdcard (sdcard/Android/data/x).

I have tried adding android:installLocation="preferExternal" in hopes of being able to see the app files on the sdcard where they requested it, but it has not made a difference.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: please also share the code of what you tried

Comment: `from a directory on the sdcard (sdcard/Android/data/x).` That is an external storage location. Has nothing to do with a removable micro sd card. Please rephrase your post as you used sdcard all the time wrong.